# I want to prove: $|f'(a)| \leq \frac{M}{1-|a|^2}$ so, what is the technic for use this Hint in down:

Tags: complex-integration

We have $f$ is a function holomorphic on $D(0,1)$, bounded by $M>0$,
how to use this hint :
 $$\frac{1}{1-|a|^2}= \frac{1}{2i\pi} \int_{|z|=1}  \frac{1}{z|z-a|^2}  \,dz$$

Comment: This seems like something you could tackle using Cauchy's formula, but I can't seem to fully get there